# Slice data by label

Tags: r

Within R, I am trying to slice data imported from a text file such that it is stored within a dedicated variable. I wish to have the column data from recup.txt matching the label 'placebo' stored in a variable called placebo and I thought using slices would be the viable method. My R code:

```
placebo <- recup %>% slice("Type",placebo)
print(placebo)
```

The output from the above gives me the data in ascending order from the two different labels, one after the other instead of only one which is what I sought.

[image: rstudio_output]

I am starting to wonder if it would be preferable for me to use `select()` or the `dplyr` library instead.

Comment: Maybe use the `split()` function to make a list of individual data frames.

Comment: `placebo <- recup[which(recup$Type == "placebo"),]` using base R or `placebo <- recup %>% filter(Type == "placebo")` using `dplyr`